# How to set default `option` in indexed Angular `select` tag?

Tags: angularjs

The default `option` for my `select` tag is blank. I want it to be "Value" instead.

Here's my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hrcnOCANfzaNEZacQo7R?p=info

Why does this show up blank? How would I make the default `option` tag read "Value" and have the `value` attribute "value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with a blank option:

```
<select ng-model="customize[$index].selectedDataTransform">
    <option value="">Value</option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in dataTransform" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Or setting `ng-model` with a default value:

```
<select ng-model="customize[$index].selectedDataTransform || 'value'">
    <option ng-repeat="option in dataTransform" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Refer [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0EJVWsIGIlJfhrLKadJ9?p=preview).

**Mention:**

If the default option's value is blank, when `ng-model` is unsetted, the blank option will be selected automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-init to assign the select model

`ng-init="customize[$index].selectedDataTransform = dataTransform[0].value"`

```
<select ng-model="customize[$index].selectedDataTransform" ng-init="customize[$index].selectedDataTransform = dataTransform[0].value">
     <option ng-repeat="option in dataTransform" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/nCfCdTt1gHl5Y6XilQpn?p=preview)